# What do Chocobos eat?

Tags: final-fantasy

My knowledge of [Chocobos](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocobo) is lacking in the sense that I'd like to know more about their eating habits and preferences concerning the different types of foods available to them in [Gaia/Planet](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gaia_(Final_Fantasy_VII)).

More precisely, is a [Chocobo](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Chocobo) considered herbivore or carnivore; no doubt they must be omnivore?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Chocobos eat "Greens" which according to [the wikia](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Greens) looks like normal vegetables

[image: Greens image from the wikia]

> Various Greens from Final Fantasy VII.

generally the main Greens they are fed is Gysahl Greens which according to the page is the golden looking carrot under the eggplant in the image above (or at least that's what they look like in *Final Fantasy VII*)

to my understanding Chocobos are herbivores where in *Final Fantasy XII* they only attack living creatures to defend themselves, flock and/territory as opposed to hunting them for food

Comment: The "Golden carrot" is most likely based on the Daikon, a giant white radish-like vegetable popular in Japan.

Answer (score 14):

In the original FF2 SNES version, you used carrots to call the Big Chocobo. I couldn't find an appropriate picture or video, so I just recorded it myself; you can watch it on twitch [here](https://www.twitch.tv/videos/302852257##).

[image: Smells like Chocobos]

[image: What to use]

[image: Big Chocobo]

Comment: Edited the images into the answer itself, you can do so by clicking on the image icon on the editor and even uploading them or using a link from the web.

Comment: Thanks!  I was trying to add the images via the image icon, but it wouldn't take just the prnt.scr links for some reason...

Comment: The links were to the web page not the images, I just downloaded the images from your location and uploaded them to the answer itself from my PC.

Comment: Yeah, I'm an idiot -- there's an "Images" word in the editor UI, which is what I was clicking on...  Never saw the picture icon version to upload them until I edited the post to see how you did what you did.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries, there are a few quirks to how things work here, not always the easiest things to work out.

Comment: Geez seeing these images brought back some old memories.

Answer (score 11):

It would seem that they are herbivores, [their diet consisting of plants and fruit](http://www.ffxivgardening.com/seed-list.php?SeedType=1).

(Only food names retained in list, but all are marked as "Chocobo Food")

> - Cieldalaes Pineapple ...
> - Curiel Root ...
> - Doman Plum ...
> - Gysahl Greens ...
> - Han Lemon ...
> - Krakka Root ...
> - Mamook Pear   ...
> - Mimett Gourd ...
> - O'Ghomoro Berry ...
> - Pahsana Fruit ...
> - Sylkis Bud ...
> - Tantalplant ...
> - Thavnairian Onion ...
> - Valfruit ...
> - Xelphatol Apple ...

Answer (score 7):

In FF7, you can keep, train, and breed chocobos. This is only possible with plants, they will not eat anything else in your inventory. While not definitive proof, this seems pretty solid evidence that they are herbivores.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example of a plant?

Comment: @aitía as an FF7 player, one of the (most famous) example is Gysahl Greens which has been mentioned on other answers.